# Android image view after cropping only displays small image

Tags: android, image, imageview, crop

I'm trying to make an android application that allows the user to capture an image and then send it to server for further processing but before that the user is required to crop the image. I have used the following code to invoke the crop intent and display the image on the image view but unfortunately the image displayed after cropping is very small ( almost like a thumbnail ), Here case 1 is when the camera is selected, case 2 for selecting from gallery.

```
case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the image uri from earlier
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                // notify any apps of any changes we make
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

                // create a content resolver object which will allow us to access the image file at the uri above
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                // create an empty bitmap object
                Bitmap bitmap;

                try {
                    // get the bitmap from the image uri using the content resolver api to get the image
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    // set the bitmap to the image view
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(Uploader.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   cropimage(selectedImage);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // notify the user
                    Toast.makeText(Uploader.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
```

cropimage method :

```
public void cropimage(Uri selectedImage)
{
    //indicate image type and Uri     
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded",true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

    return;
}
```

PIC_CROP holds the value 3. Inside onActivityResult :

```
 case 3:
                if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //get the returned data
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                   //get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    if(extras!=null)
                    {
                         bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    }
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                  //  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


                }
```

The displayed image on the image view is very small. I need the image view to display the cropped image in the actual dimensions. Please help me fix this problem.
Below is the xml code for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.kart.counter.Upload_photo">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgdsp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload and check"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="imageupload"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Cropping image]

[image: ImageView displaying small image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use to crop, the image lost quality and size, for that, to work with ImageView with layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_height="wrap_content" doesn't show good, you need set a size and play with scaleType attribute.

Check http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html